# Vecrtorized evluation of function defined by matrix over grid

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to plot the value of a function defined by a matrix over a grid of values.

Let `S` be an invertable 2x2 matrix and let `x` be a 2-dimensional vector.  How can vectorize the evaluation of `x@S@x` over a two dimensional grid?

Here is how I currently do it.  It works, but takes a beat to perform the computation since the grid is so fine.

```
#Initialize Matrix
S = np.zeros(shape = (2,2))

while np.linalg.matrix_rank(S)<S.shape[1]:
    S = np.random.randint(-5,5+1, size = (2,2))


X,Y = [j.ravel() for j in np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,1001),np.linspace(-2,2,1001))]

Z = np.zeros_like(X)

for i,v in enumerate(zip(X,Y)):
    v = np.array(v)
    Z[i] = v@S@v

n = int(np.sqrt(X.size))
Z = Z.reshape(n,n)
X = X.reshape(n,n)
Y = Y.reshape(n,n)
plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest would be with stacking those `X,Y` into a 2-column 2D array and then using [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to replace the loopy matrix-multiplications -

```
p = np.column_stack((X,Y)) # or np.stack((X,Y)).T
Zout = np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',p,S,p,optimize=True)
```